# I welcome being reminded to stand but can't stand the constant exercise ring-related messaging. How can I turn those off on my Apple watch?

Tags: messages, apple-watch, reminders

I find the stand reminders extremely helpful, and I like how my Apple Watch keeps track of various exercise activities; when I forget to start a walk or a bicycle ride the watch notices and asks to start the session for me.

However I get many completely unhelpful and distracting (to me) messages about exercise rings each day. I'd like all exercise ring-related messages to cease. In addition to needless distraction they prevent my watch from being useful; sometimes I get a exercise ring message, I press the knob thinking I will return to my watch face but instead get a Heptapod B-like light show with burst of swirling color which lasts several seconds. I can't use my watch for anything until the show finishes.

**Question:** I welcome being reminded to stand but can't stand the constant exercise ring-related messaging. How can I turn *all of those messages off* on my Apple watch?

Also, is it possible to turn off the "You did it!" message after I stand up without turning off the reminder to stand up?

---

Example of Heptapod B from [Github](https://github.com/WolframResearch/Arrival-Movie-Live-Coding/tree/master/ScriptLogoJpegs):

[image: Example of Heptapod B from https://github.com/WolframResearch/Arrival-Movie-Live-Coding/tree/master/ScriptLogoJpegs]